# .htaccess a specific folder is not rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

There is something strange going on. I am using Zend Framework on a subfolder in a site. I have a modular structure to my website, so the links consist of module names (*www.xx.com/**modulename***). I have created a .htaccess file for the root dir, so that all of the requests would be routed to the **public** dir.

When i try to access the homepage ( *www.xx.com*) or any module it all goes exactly as it should. **www.xx.com/authentication**, **www.xx.com/sample** or **www.xx.com/deathmetalreallyrox** are all working as they should. But when I try to connect to **www.xx.com/admin**, it crashes and BURNS!!!! It does work however with **www.xx.com/public/admin/**.

Could it be, that my Hosting provider has set up some sort of rule in the httpd.conf to prevent me from accessing the *admin* section in my hosting?
Here's my .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteRule  ^(browse|config).*  - [L]
ErrorDocument 500 /error-docs/500.shtml
SetEnv CACHE_OFFSET 2678400
SetEnv APP_DOMAIN http://www.xx.com/public
SetEnv APP_PREF /public

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Fri, 25 Sep 2037 19:30:32 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(adm|statistics) - [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) public/admin/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Help?

EDIT:
Browser error msg:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But when I try to connect to www.xx.com/admin, it crashes and BURNS"? Do you get a 500 error? A redirect loop?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot that part, edited.

Comment: What purpose is `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) public/admin/$1` meant to serve here?

Comment: There was a problem, that the call for admin was not going to admin, so I thought, that there was some sort of a glitch in the routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that the server was somehow configured wrongly.

As I do not have the total control over the server, I couldn't know, that there was a rule in the httpd.conf, that denied access to any folder named **admin** or **administrator**, so that when I tried to get the contents of a folder by this name, Apache first checked, if a folder by this name existed, and denied it by default.

***So, the concise answer, the server was configured wrongly, didn't allow access to specific folders.***

Answer (score 0):

You redirect anything starting with `admin/` to `public/admin/` first and then everything to `public/whatever`. So when you request `/admin/`, it's trying to give you `/public/public/admin/`, which doesn't exist, so you get a 404.

Try removing the line `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) public/admin/$1`. It's already handled by the next line, and you don't want to do it twice.

Comment: Yes, but while that is true, it wasnt the cause. Answered by self.